# Searching for and working with characters within a range

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames.

In `df1`, I have a column of International Classification of Diseases (ICD) diagnosis codes (`df1$PriDiag`), as well as other information.

```
#df1
PriDiag = c("A051","A067","A161","A242","A459") 
Admissions = c("106","79","67","50","41") 
Pts = c("97","27","45","30","20") 
df1 = data.frame(PriDiag,Admissions,Pts) 
df1
  PriDiag Admissions Pts
1    A051        106  97
2    A067         79  27
3    A161         67  45
4    A242         50  30
5    A459         41  20
```

In the other data frame (`df2`), I have start (`df2$Start`) and end (`df2$End`) limits of the ICD sub-categories, and the relating description (`df2$Description`).

```
#df2
Start = c("A00","A15","A20","A30") 
End = c("A09","A19","A28","A49") 
Description = c("Intestinal infectious diseases","Tuberculosis","Certain zoonotic bacterial","Other bacterial diseases")
df2 = data.frame(Start,End,Description) 
df2
Start End                         Description
1   A00 A09      Intestinal infectious diseases
2   A15 A19                        Tuberculosis
3   A20 A28 Certain zoonotic bacterial diseases
4   A30 A49            Other bacterial diseases
```

What I want to do is assign a new column to `df1` with the sub-category description (`df2$Description`) of the code (`df1$PriDiag`). I would be able to do this if the codes were numeric and not characters, but I am struggling to work out a quick solution. Is there a method of searching between characters?

My desired result would be a new data frame, `df3`, which would look something like this:

```
df3
PriDiag Admissions Pts                         Description
1    A051        106  97      Intestinal infectious diseases
2    A067         79  27      Intestinal infectious diseases
3    A161         67  45                        Tuberculosis
4    A242         50  30 Certain zoonotic bacterial diseases
5    A459         41  20            Other bacterial diseases
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select df1.*, df2.Description 
       from df1 
       left join df2
       on PriDiag between Start and End"
)
```

giving:

```
  PriDiag Admissions Pts                    Description
1    A051        106  97 Intestinal infectious diseases
2    A067         79  27 Intestinal infectious diseases
3    A161         67  45                   Tuberculosis
4    A242         50  30     Certain zoonotic bacterial
5    A459         41  20       Other bacterial diseases
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of the sqldf package, it looks very useful. I had never come across it before.

Answer (score 0):

This makes some assumptions about your data that may not be true.  It could be tweaked if your data is not as straight forward as it looks but the path of least resistance is my favorite one.

```
library(qdap)

## Create a list key based on ranges
key <- setNames(lapply(1:nrow(df2), function(i) {
    paste0(strtrim(df2[i, 1], 1), 
        pad(substring(df2[i, 1], 2):substring(df2[i, 2], 2), 2))
}), df2[, 3])

## Assuming that last digit isn't important use qdap's lookup function (%l%)
df1[, "Description"] <- strtrim(df1[, 1], 3) %l% key

##   PriDiag Admissions Pts                    Description
## 1    A051        106  97 Intestinal infectious diseases
## 2    A067         79  27 Intestinal infectious diseases
## 3    A161         67  45                   Tuberculosis
## 4    A242         50  30     Certain zoonotic bacterial
## 5    A459         41  20       Other bacterial diseases
```